# Create folder names based of filename (before bracket)

Tags: batch-file

I've been looking everywhere but I cannot find the answer to this specific question.  I've only just started using batch scripts for file/folder manipulation and have a good grasp of concepts, but I can't quite work out the solution.

Situation:
I have thousands of files which have the format 'name (some info).ext'

I'm looking for a way to extract the information before the space-bracket and then create a folder with that information.
After this I want to move that file to that folder.

Can anyone direct me how I do this?

Comment: IMHO, try Powershell instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  

I didn't think of using Powershell and managed to find some help at the following link:
https://superuser.com/questions/966007/batch-create-folders-based-on-file-names-excluding-parenthesis-and-brackets

With a small modification I was able to get the results I was after.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest this, *(based on your now deleted answer)*:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "targetdir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\testfolder"

CD /D "%targetdir%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For %%A In (*.rp2) Do For /F %%B In ("%%~nA") Do (
    If Not Exist "%%~B\" MD "%%~B"
    Move /Y "%%A" "%%~B">Nul)
```

And here's a version to also cater for file names containing spaces and those with `0` or more spaces before the opening parenthesis. *It should additionally include those without parentheses too*:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "targetdir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\testfolder"

CD /D "%targetdir%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Set "_="
For %%A In (*.rp2) Do For /F "Delims=(" %%B In ("%%~nA"
) Do Call :Sub "%%A" "%%B"
Exit /B

:Sub
If Not Defined _ Set "_=%~2"
If "%_:~-1%"==" " (Set "_=%_:~,-1%" & GoTo Sub) 
If Not Exist "%_%\" MD "%_%"
Move /Y %1 "%_%">Nul
Set "_="
```

Comment: This will not work if the name itself contains a space.

Comment: I'm aware of its limitations, @FatalBulletHit; the answer, as stated, was based on the code they'd provided themselves as an answer.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you aren't aware of its limitations, but somebody else who reads this in the future may not know. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%G IN ("C:\adjust\path\*.ext") DO (
    SET "folder_name=%%~nG"
    CALL :create_dir
    MOVE "%%G" "%%~dpG!folder_name!\%%~nxG"
)

PAUSE
EXIT

:create_dir
SET "end_bit=!folder_name:*(=!"
SET "folder_name=!folder_name:%end_bit%=!
SET "folder_name=!folder_name:~0,-2!"
MD "!folder_name!" >nul 2>&1
EXIT /B
```

This will create the directory `example` for `example (info).ext` and move that file in said directory.